# Transfer a huge directory between servers (one of them has no ssh)

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

So we switched from some crappy shared hosting provider to a dedicated server and I'm trying to transfer a 250+ GB directory from the old crappy server (which I don't have ssh access to), to the new server (which i have root access to).

so RSYNC, SCP, etc. are out of the question.

I'm trying to figure out how i can do this without downloading all the files and re-uploading them. I would like to just set it in motion, go home for the weekend, and come back to it.

How would i FTP into my old server from my new server?

Comment: I think that if you examine the archives here you'll find the answer you are seeking.  This question has been asked and answered a number of different times.

Comment: Might be best asked on SuperUser SE....

Comment: What kind of access do you have to the old server?  Are you saying you have no access at all?  You only mentioned that you don't have ssh access.  Find what access you do have, then find a way to use that method to perform a transfer.  We can't help, because we don't know anything about the source server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and use ncftp or ncftpget from the new server recursively to get the whole directory structure and files

```
ncftpget -R yourremotehost . /
```

check http://www.ncftp.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access to the new server, you can do whatever you want on it.  Use a console FTP client (it's just called ftp usually) and FTP in.  You could download the files using that, or using wget, or you could even probably install gnome and filezilla, use X forwarding to launch it, and transfer all the files (don't do that).  In short, there is no trick here.

If you use a console utility to transfer files all weekend, you may want to look at using screen so you don't need to keep the SSH session open.

Answer (score 0):

Upload a script to the old server that can do scp or FTP. Execute that script.

Answer (score 0):

you can do wget/curl from the new server as you have SSH access.